# Excel: Compare 2 columns and pull missing data into 3rd column

Tags: excel, vba, function, vlookup

Been searching like crazy but can't find exactly what I'm looking for.

Column A: Some employees (Partial List)

Column E: All employees (Complete List)

I need Column C to be populated with all other employees not in Column A (Column A compared to Column E to pull data into Column C that is not in Column A).

I have tried IF, VLOOKUP functions and have come close but don't want any blank cells in Column C.

I would prefer a VBA code (as column A and C are linked to an external datasource) and are populated using VBA.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you give https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask a quick read you'll see that you didn't provide most of the information needed for a "good question".  If you edit this and add in as much of that as you can, then you'll get much better responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub test()

Dim LastRowA As Long
Dim LastRowC As Long
Dim LastRowE As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim NameNotExist As Boolean

LastRowA =Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowC = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowE = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRowE
    For j = 1 To LastRowA
        NameNotExist = False
        If Sheet1.Range("E" & i).Value =Sheet1.Range("A" & j).Value Then
            Exit For
        Else
            NameNotExist = True
        End If
    Next j
    If NameNotExist = True Then
        If LastRowC = 1 And Sheet1.Range("C1").Value = "" Then
          Sheet1.Range("C1").Value =Sheet1.Range("E" & i).Value
        Else:
            LastRowC =Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
           Sheet1.Range("C" & LastRowC + 1).Value = Sheet1.Range("E" & i).Value
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason, VBA gets stuck running the code, not sure why

Comment: @David Hessel Check it again

Comment: Still have the same issue :/

Comment: It works fine for me.could you please provide any details?

Comment: The code just keeps running and nothing happens in the workbook. I have to End it

Comment: Is there a way to do it with VLOOKUP fn? And skip the blank cells to have 1 complete list? Thanks for your input thus far!